Unable to Show Google Pay Button in Stripe Payment Sheet in Flutter
I’m trying to integrate Google Pay with Stripe in my Flutter app to display a Google Pay button in the payment sheet. I followed the steps in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lUaLjSe4y4, but the button does not appear.
Has anyone successfully implemented this feature? If so, could you point out any common mistakes or additional steps that might be required?
I’m using the flutter_stripe package.
Google Pay is enabled in my Stripe dashboard.
The Google Pay button should appear within the Stripe Payment Sheet when opened in my Flutter app, allowing users to select Google Pay as a payment method.

if google-pay is already enabled on stripe dashboard, then following should work:
for g-pay button:
PlatformPayButton(onPressed: (){
 _handleGooglePayPress(),
}) 

this will show apple pay on ios and g-pay on android
furthermore,
if you have client secret or get it from backend api, you can do following to further confirm the payment:
void _handleGooglePayPress() async {
    print('pay pressed');
    try {
      print('trying');
      final SecretResponse response =
          await CustomerOrderRepository().submitOrder();
      print('response.clientSecret: ${response.clientSecret}');
      if (response.clientSecret != null) {
        try {
          final paymentIntentResult =
              await Stripe.instance.confirmPlatformPayPaymentIntent(
            clientSecret: response.clientSecret!,
            confirmParams: PlatformPayConfirmParams.googlePay(
              googlePay: GooglePayParams(
                merchantCountryCode: 'AU',
                currencyCode: 'AUD',
              ),
            ),
          );
          print('paymentIntentResult: $paymentIntentResult');
          print(
              'paymentIntentResult.status: ${response.customerOrderDTO?.toJson()}');
          if (paymentIntentResult.status == PaymentIntentsStatus.Succeeded) {
            _navigateToNextScreen(
                orderTotalPrice, response.customerOrderDTO?.orderNumber);
          } else {
            throw Exception(
                'Payment failed with status: ${paymentIntentResult.status}');
          }
        } catch (err) {
          print('Error: $err');
          String errorMessage = 'Error during payment';
          if (err is StripeException) {
            errorMessage = err.error.localizedMessage!;
          }
          CommonMethods.showFailreToast(errorMessage);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error: $error');
      CommonMethods.showFailreToast('Something Went Wrong - $error');
    }
  }

this works for me
i hope it helps.
